# Python - how to use the dict() function with only a variable?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, split

I have a variable called "dict_str" that looks like this : `"a = 15, a2 = 19"` (it continue for thousands of inputs).
If I try to use the `dict()` function :

```
dict(dict_str)
```

it gives me this error :

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

But if I do this :

```
 dict(a = 15, a2 = 19)
```

it works fine.
So I am wondering if there's a way to make it works with the `dict_str` variable

Comment: you need to convert the string into something that dict can use. Look into "split" for a start.

Comment: **strings are not source code**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a work around.

```py
items = [item.split('=') for item in dict_str.split(', ')]

my_dict = {}
for key, value in items:
    my_dict[key.strip()] = int(value.strip())

print(my_dict)
```

If you prefer a [dict comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/) you can use the bellow approach

```py
items = [item.split('=') for item in dict_str.split(', ')]
my_dict = {key.strip(): int(value.strip()) for key, value in items}
print(my_dict)
```

---

```
{'a': 15, 'a2': 19}
```

You could even use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) depending on your use case.

Example:

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(\w+) *= *(\d+)') 
items = regex.findall(dict_str)
my_dict = {key: int(value) for key, value in items} 

print(my_dict)
```

This regex should produce same output.

Comment: I don't understand the 3/4 of this but it works so thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

### One liner:

```
dmap = dict(map(str.strip, array.split("=")) for array in "a = 15, a2 = 19".split(","))
```

### Decompressing it:

```
data = "a = 15, a2 = 19" 

dmap = dict(map(str.strip, array.split("=")) for array in data.split(","))

print(dmap)
```

### Better approach:

```
data = "a = 15, a2 = 19"

dmap = {}

for value in data.split(","):
    array = value.split("=")
    dmap[array[0].strip()] = int(array[1].strip())
```